# Insertar array en una tabla desde ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente `Ajax`

```
$(function() {
    //function ajax
    $('#example-table #btn-analisisInterno').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elemento = $(this);
        var idArt = elemento.parent().parent().find('#id_articulo').text();
        console.log(idArt);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/visualizarArt',
            method: 'post',
            data: { idArticulo: idArt },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                //document.getElementById('artic').innerHTML = id;
                 $('#example tbody').append("<tr><td>" + res.SI_Articulo + "</td><td>" + res.SI_Existencia + "</td><td>" + res.SI_Ubicacion + "</td></tr>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

el cuál me hace una una consulta a sql y me trae los siguientes datos en un array

**Consulta**

```
getVisualizarArticulo: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('Entra');
        var id = req.body.idArticulo;
        var config = require('.././database/config');
        console.log(id);
        var art = null;
        var respuesta = { res: false };
        sql.connect(config)
            .then(function() {
                var request2 = new sql.Request();
                request2.query("SELECT SI_Articulo, SI_Ubicacion, SI_Existencia FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD WHERE SI_Articulo = '" + req.body.idArticulo + "'")
                    .then(function(recordset) {
                        art = recordset['recordset'];
                        console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
                        console.log('Affected: ' + request2.rowsAffected);
                        const articulos = art;
                        console.log(articulos);
                        sql.close();
                        respuesta.res = true;
                        res.json(articulos);

                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Request error: ' + err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
                }
            });
    }

(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{SI_Articulo: "200002", SI_Ubicacion: "FF1031", SI_Existencia: 28}
1
:
{SI_Articulo: "200002", SI_Ubicacion: "o293534a", SI_Existencia: 11}
2
:
{SI_Articulo: "200002", SI_Ubicacion: "o293894a", SI_Existencia: 16}
3
:
{SI_Articulo: "200002", SI_Ubicacion: "o293894d", SI_Existencia: 17}
4
:
{SI_Articulo: "200002", SI_Ubicacion: "TRANSCLI", SI_Existencia: 1}
```

Está es la informacion que me trae en `console.log(res);`

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es ingresar esa informacion a una tabla html y como esa tabla esta en un modal cada que lo consulto se deberia limpiar y volver a ingresar los datos.

Comment: paso 1: desenpaquetar el array, paso 2 formatearlo, paso 3 escribirlo en el html, eso es lo que te hace falta cuando tengas algun codigo sobre estos escenarios podremos ayudarte. por ahora es muy generica tu pregunta

Comment: ¿Podrias agregar el codigo en php que hace la consulta y te devuelve el array?

Comment: podrías vaciar el contenido de la tabla antes de la llamada ajax: `$('#example tbody').empty()`

Comment: No esta en php, esta en nodejs

Comment: @LeonPlata Muchas gracas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu código, en la línea donde usas el `append` estás agregando los resultados a la tabla, pero primero debes recorrer el objeto para obtener de cada propiedad su valor.

Ejemplo *en javascript*:

```
// Variables para almacenar los valores de las propiedades de tu objeto "res".
var si_articulo = "";
var si_existencia = "";
var si_ubicacion = "";

// Recorre el objeto para obtener los resultados:
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

    // Obtienes los valores de las propiedades según recorres el objeto.
    si_articulo = res[i].SI_Articulo;
    si_existencia = res[i].SI_Existencia;
    si_ubicacion = res[i].SI_Ubicacion;

    // Ahora si agregas la información obtenida a tu tabla HTML:
    $('#example tbody').append("<tr><td>" + si_articulo + "</td><td>" + si_existencia +"</td><td>" + si_ubicacion + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.